Zabbix 7.0 HA not working for Agent-Proxy communication breakdown
Zabbix 7.0 HA not working for Agent-Proxy communication breakdown
Referred to blog - https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-7-0-p...lancing/28173/
Issue:
Failover doesn't happen when proxy is online but unreachable from agent or vice versa
The blog mentions that this is not possible with the new Zabbix 7.0 HA and Load Balancing logic.
Scenario:
2 proxy setup in a proxy group (proxy1 and proxy2)
agent mapped to proxy1
both proxies working fine
agent-proxy1 communication breakdown
proxy1 tells agent to go to proxy2 but since the frontend mapping is still with proxy1, the packets are not captured by proxy2
this keeps on happening until frontend mapping changes are done manually
Question:
Has anyone tried this out and made it work with some workaround?
Is my thinking correct when I say that a custom script can be created for HA in case of agent-proxy communication breakdown with a call to the function that is responsible for HA in case of proxy going down?
I tried to find the code logic but couldn't. If anyone knows, please hep me with the function that is responsible for Proxy HA in case of proxy going down.
Screenshot from blog
Failover doesn't happen when proxy is online but unreachable from agent or vice versa
The blog mentions that this is not possible with the new Zabbix 7.0 HA and Load Balancing logic.
Scenario:
2 proxy setup in a proxy group (proxy1 and proxy2)
agent mapped to proxy1
both proxies working fine
agent-proxy1 communication breakdown
proxy1 tells agent to go to proxy2 but since the frontend mapping is still with proxy1, the packets are not captured by proxy2
this keeps on happening until frontend mapping changes are done manually
